# How do I solve this without recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to help my son solve a math problem.  This seems like a good opportunity to expose him to some programming.  I can see the recursive solution but perhaps an iterative one would be easier to explain.  The language he has learned so far has been [SmallBasic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/cc950524.aspx) which doesn't support recursion very well (no local variables).  I'm not against teaching another language, but still want to understand if there is a good way to solve this without recursion.

The problem is this:
Given the sequence of numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, insert +'s and -'s between numbers so that the result adds up to 101.  For instance, 1+23+4+5+67-8+9=101.

The recursive solution looks something like this:

```
next(total, number, nextNumber, sequenceString)
{
    //add
    next(total + number, ...);

    //subtract
    next(total - number, ...);

    //do nothing (multiply)
    next(total, number * 10, ...);
}
```

Is there an iterative solution to this that isn't terribly complex?

Comment: There is another post on this subject: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)

Comment: 1+2-3+4-5+6+7+89 = 101
1-2+3+4+5-6+7+89 = 101
1+23-4+5-6-7+89 = 101
123+4+56+7-89 = 101
12-3+4-5+6+78+9 = 101
1+23+4+5+67-8+9 = 101
1+2+34+56+7-8+9 = 101
1-2+34+5-6+78-9 = 101
1+2+3+45+67-8-9 = 101
12+34+5+67-8-9 = 101

Ten print operators will solve the problem

Comment: This was really fun to write in C#. It seems so easy on the surface. In the end, it took me a few hours to iron the bugs out and I had to find 2 additional libraries online. Thanks for the exercise.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider the spaces between the numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
There are 8 such interstitial spaces or slots.

Each such space can be filled by +, -, or nothing (indicating a
longer number being formed).

That's three possibilities in each of eight slots.  Assign digits to the three possible fillers as:

```
 0 --> +
 1 --> -
 2 --> (nothing)
```

Now every 8-digit trinary string corresponds to a solution.  For examples:

```
 00000000 --> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9
 00000001 --> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8-9
 00000002 --> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+89
 22222222 --> 123456789
```

Now write a simple loop that counts from 00000000 to 22222222 in trinary.
Interpret each number along the way as a solution as above, stop as soon as you hit a solution yielding the target, 101, or report failure if you get to the end without hitting the target value.

There are 3^8 (exponent, not xor, or 3**8 for the fortranoids, or

```
 3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3
```

for the intensively literal-minded) possible solutions.  That's only 6561; you can brute-force it this way quite handily.

Comment: This is correct and useful (and I voted it up), but I think recursion, if explained well, will be simpler.

Comment: While it's true that the recursive formulation is a simple, tail-recursive function, the implementation environment available in the question is likely to make it ugly and not a good demonstration of recursion.

Answer (score 4):

Recursion is an important point in computer science. If your purpose of this is to teach your son, why don't you explain him recursion right now? ;)

Comment: I probably can and will, but that doesn't solve my curiosity about a non-recursive solution.

Comment: You can *always* write an iterative equivalent of a recursive solution but I don't think the iterative counterpart of your problem is as trival as the recursive one.

Comment: It's pretty trivial, I'll post it in a few minutes

Comment: Oh, I've just seen he's 8, so it's not something he'd understand easily :(

Comment: Seb, don't underestimate kids by any means. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 basic operations:

- Add (option "0");
- Substract (option "1");
- Do nothing (option "2");

So basically you have 3^8 possible solutions; just try them all.

This is PHP code, but includes converting numbers in other bases, which is something an 8 year-old boy probably wouldn't understand quickly. Maybe you can find the twist for this:

```
<?php

$limit = pow(3, 8);
for($op = 0; $op < $limit; $op++){
  // Get this operation.
  $op_base3 = base_convert($op, 10, 3);

  // Fill leading 0's.
  $op_base3 = str_pad($op_base3, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

  // Here you get something like 00212120, which would say:
  // 1[+]2[+]3[nothing]4[-]5[nothing]6[-]7[nothing]8[+]9
  // That's: 1+2+34-56-78+9

  // Compute and if result's correct, output solution.
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be solved with simple iteration. You only have to convert the string to stack.

Comment: It's not tail recursion, because there are three separate recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited depth of recursion, an array can be used as a stack.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done iteratively, but not nearly as simply as this.  More importantly, are you going to use this as an opportunity to teach your son about algorithm complexity?